# Button action not executed

Tags: swift, button, selector

I'm creating a little scrollable menu with buttons. The menu is created with the button labels but when I click on the button the action is not executed. I'm using the following code:

```
for i in 0...4 {

        var aButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        aButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Hello"), for: .normal)
       aButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        aButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        aButton.tag = i
        aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scrollButAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        var aLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xCoord,y: 40, width: buttonWidth, height: 24))
        aLabel.text = labArr[i]
        aLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        aLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        aLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 14)
        scrollView?.addSubview(aButton)
        scrollView?.addSubview(aLabel)

        xCoord += buttonWidth + buffer

    }
```

And my scrollButAction function is:

```
func scrollButAction(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {

    case 0:

        print("Hello #0")

    case 1:

       print("Hello #1")

    case 2:

       print("Hello #2")

    case 3:

        print("Hello #3")

    case 4:


        print("Hello #4")

    default:

        print("default")

    }
}
```

Comment: you may need to set the buttons delegate and datasource

Comment: Are you creating the menu and buttons in the story board or programatically?

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan programatically

Comment: @Tom This code works for me. Can you please upload a sample project in dropbox